# how to fetch the data (UserName and Password) from data table and use it to login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I dont have any idea what to do after this. I just want to create a login page but i dont know any codes to the post method of login controller.

This is my usermodel

```
 public class UserModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(UserModel userModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //No Idea
        }


        return View(userModel);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors, like where your data comes from. Take a look at [this guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/writing-a-sample-login-page-in-asp-net-mvc/), it may set you on your path.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am creating a login page where a page fetches the data(UserName and Password) from data table and if it matches then only it will logs in. and i dont know how to do that.

Comment: "dont know any codes"   Google it, try something, you will fail, show us your failure. Then, finally, you will be within our abilities.

Comment: And when it comes to login functionality, don't ever, ever, ever try to come up with your own solution. This is something that's very tricky and should never be done tried without a full understanding of security (and in some cases the laws, regulations, requirements). Example: You don't store a password ever. You store a hash and salt. You don't fetch the record to see if it matches, you see if there is a match and only allow limited information to be returned so it can't accidentally leak to a malicious end user. etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, press File/New Solution.  Tick the box for user accounts.

This will create you a complete web site example, including login pages, user account managment etc.